# Im trying to get users email id from the firebase realtime database. But whenever i run this piece of code. it keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

following references created. whenever I run the code it crashes after loading to this page. and when I comment that part of the code it works properly. I'm trying to get the data from firebase, the email id of the current user.
this is the snapshot of firebase [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHsCc.png)

```
 FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
//FirebaseUser named=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference ref=database.getReference("Users");



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user value=dataSnapshot.getValue(user.class);
            Toast.makeText(mainPage.this, " "+ value.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

//this is what appears in the error

```
2018-10-28 01:21:08.146 9706-9706/com.example.user.trip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.trip, PID: 9706
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: user_name
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzae(Unknown Source:48)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.<init>(Unknown Source:303)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:130)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.example.user.trip.mainPage$2.onDataChange(mainPage.java:86)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
2018-10-28 01:21:08.223 1890-2002/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '9bc8488 com.example.user.trip/com.example.user.trip.mainPage (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-10-28 01:21:08.223 1890-2002/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '4b5a24d com.example.user.trip/com.example.user.trip.loginPage.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-10-28 01:21:09.311 1890-2053/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
```

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: when you run the app on the phone and it crashes, check the logcat to see what the error is

Comment: did the changes

Comment: Please edit the question to show the `user` class code.

Comment: Please edit the question code `ref` has an empty child with contents like `user.`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the `user` class code and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in the `user` class to be `User_name` instead of user_name.

Or, if you do not care, above that variable write this:

`@PropertyName("User_name)
private String user_name = ""`

Or you can change your database structure to have the node `User_name` as `user_name`.

Basically, it's case sensitive.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping. actually, I just included setters too in my user class. then it started working normally. Thanks again tho.

Comment: I would imagine adding setters would eliminate the functionality of the firebase class call, but as long as it works. Glad you figured it out.